# Subsetting formula objects in R

Tags: r, regression, subset, lm

Given any `formula` object (e.g., `f`) below, I was wondering how I could separate *tilda sign* and *everything after it* and convert it into a `formula` object?

My **desired output** only in this example case is: `~ es.type+weeks` as a `formula` object.

**NOTE:** `f` could be ANY formula, the above `f` is just an example. I'm looking for a general solution.

```
f <- formula(dint ~ es.type+weeks) # Only as an example

g <- paste0(f[[1]], f[[3]]) # No success

as.formula(g)    # No success
```

Comment: You may need `all.vars(f)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to drop the terms based on the number of terms in the formula

```
g <- formula(drop.terms(terms(f), 3))
g
#~es.type + weeks

f1 <- formula(dint ~ es.type:weeks)
formula(drop.terms(terms(f1), 3))
#~es.type:weeks
```

---

It would be better to create a function to applied for different formulas

```
form1 <- function(form) {
      i1 <- length(terms(form)) + 1
       formula(drop.terms(terms(form), i1))

 }
f1 <- formula(dint ~ es.type+weeks+dd)
f2 <- formula(dint ~ es.type+weeks) 
form1(f1)
#~es.type + weeks + dd
form1(f2)
#~es.type + weeks
```

If we need to add a new term

```
update(form1(f2), ~time +.)
#~time + es.type + weeks
```

Comment: This seems needlessly complicated

Answer (score 2):

You can just manipulate the formula directly:

```r
f <- y ~ x1 + x2:x3

f[[2]] <- f[[3]]
f[[3]] <- NULL

identical(f, ~ x1 + x2:x3)
# TRUE
```